# How to swap tokens in my smart contract using pancake swap

Tags: solidity, pancakeswap

I have a BEP20 Token let's call it Token "A" in my smart contract and I want to swap it for another BEP20 Token "B" using pancake swap In my smart contract how can I write a function that uses pancake swap to do this swap? all tutorials that I found were confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [pancakeswap router docs](https://docs.pancakeswap.finance/code/smart-contracts/pancakeswap-exchange/router-v2#swapexacttokensfortokens) , play around on this. Also, you can utilize [pancakeswap testnet](https://pancake.kiemtienonline360.com/#/swap).

Comment: Thanks. do I need Factory for this too?

Comment: nope. no need. The Router handles all of the swapping mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Pancake router V2 you can swap tokens, look into

https://docs.pancakeswap.finance/code/smart-contracts/pancakeswap-exchange/router-v2#swapexacttokensfortokens

Here is the function you would need to call for swapping two tokens which you could call in your smart contract

```
        function swapTokensForExactTokens(
    uint amountOut,
    uint amountInMax,
    address[] calldata path,
    address to,
    uint deadline
    ) external virtual override ensure(deadline) returns (uint[] memory amounts) {}
```